# flutter : unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_secure_storage'

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting the following error when I tried to build my flutter android version.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_secure_storage'.
> Failed to create Jar file /Users/.gradle/caches/jars-8/fef84f4f98be9f93b0b593ccb1e3e207/lint-model-31.1.1.jar.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_secure_storage' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_secure_storage' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

The folder mention in the  error is valid but the jarfile is missing.

I have the following in my gradle file

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    
}
```

I have clean and rebuild my projects..

```
doctor -v
    Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.13.2 on channel stable at /Applications/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ff5b5b5fa6 (7 weeks ago), 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
    • Engine revision b20183e040
    • Dart version 3.1.0
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

   Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
```

I don't explicitly use this plugin and it is not in my pubspec file

Please let me know how to resolve this issue

Thanks for your help